# how to group objects in an array Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array of users who are managers.

However there are repeated Users.

I would like to group them so that there is only one instance of each User in the array.

What would be the best way to go about this?

```
@managers.sort_by{|obj| obj.id} # Just sorted the data but did not eliminate duplicats

@managers.group_by{|u|u.name}    # just created a bunch of arrays for each name
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for giving me such great answers. Really helps a NOOB learn this stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `uniq` method, which returns a new array with duplicates removed.

```
@managers.uniq
```

Comment: or @managers.uniq_by {|manager| manager.user_id} (see http://apidock.com/rails/Array/uniq_by)

Answer (score 1):

If by duplicate you mean the same object ID, then you can do the following:

```
@managers.uniq.group_by(&:name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Filtering the array feels like fixing symptoms. Why does the array contain rubbish in the first place?

I would suggest adding a `manager?` method to your `User` model that returns true if the user is a manager. Then you could to something like

```
@managers = User.select &:manager?
```

and get an array that only contains managers.

Comment: i agree with you that this looks symptomatic, but does this not lead straight to a N+1 query problem if your `manager?` method tries to find records associated to each user ? (unless using a "manager" column set to true/false by a callback when applying to a manager job/quiting)

Comment: I had a `role` column in mind, with the `manager?` method returning true if the the user had the matching role. But you are right in your scenario. I guess we don't know enough about the context given here.

Comment: In my case the way it works is the same person can be the manager of many boards they create.  So over time I would get more than one board possibly by the same manager.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do

```
Manager.select('DISTINCT user_id')
```

to get a clean array in the first place, whith better performance.